# catch invalid file paths

Tags: c#

I have a function that reads a bunch of path-values (8 or 9 of them) from a text file. It uses these paths later in the application to read files. Whats the best way to check for validity of these file-paths. Can I do a single catch of some sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.Exists` and/or `Directory.Exists` is a path can be a directory.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>{"C:\\path1.txt", "c:\\path2.txt"};
    bool allValid = paths.All(path=>File.Exists(path));
}
```

Comment: `File.Exists` will also return `false` if someone has the file locked.

Comment: @John Saunders Thanks for pointing that out, that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

System.IO.Directory.Exists(string path)
System.IO.File.Exists(string path)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) in a loop, pretty simple and readable. Is there a trendier way? Probably.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe regex could be an option for you, at least in a windows environment. This avoids making a disk access, as File.Exists would. Source: http://www.csharp411.com/check-valid-file-path-in-c/

```
public bool IsValidPath(string path)
{
  Regex r = new Regex( @"^(([a-zA-Z]\:)|(\\))(\\{1}|((\\{1})[^\\]([^/:*?<>""|]*))+)$" );
  return r.IsMatch( path );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) method. Like most of the members of the `Path` class, it validates the path you pass in and throws an `ArgumentException` if the path is invalid.